# Office Web Apps 2013 using without SharePoint

Tags: 2013, office-integration, office-web-apps, integration

Office Web Apps 2013 is now standalone service product.
SharePoint used it from iframe like this

```
https://officewebapps.contoso.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx? sharepoint_doc_handler_url + accesstoken
```

Some info [Introducing Office Web Apps Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2012/09/11/introducing-office-web-apps-server.aspx)

I want to use it in my application, but i don't know the way to generate right URL to preview document. I've got an error.

```
There's a configuration problem preventing us from getting your document. If possible, try opening this document in Microsoft Word.
```

Did anybody know how the SharePoint uses the Office Web Apps 2013 ?

Comment: As I know OWAS using WOPI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Ok. I've got it, by creating a handler to send JSON meta-information of object.